# Simple web form text field returns nothing

Tags: input, webforms, submit

I'm running into a really baffling problem where I have an extremely simple (read, newbie trying to understand) web form. The form looks like this:

```
<form id="myform">
      <input type="text" name="t" id="t" />
      <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then I have some also very simple js that I just want to use to check what the value is that the user has before doing some other things and submitting.

```
function search() 
{
    var form = document.querySelector("form");
    s = form.elements[0].value;
    alert(form.elements[0].type);
    alert(form.elements[0].value);
}
```

What I don't understand is why, whatever I do, the first alert shows type "text" like I want, and the second one returns nothing at all. It doesn't matter what's in the field, when I submit, it goes away before the javascript even catches it.

I also tried

```
document.forms["myform"].addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And it seemed to have no effect on the fact that the page always submits when I refresh, but it did stop my button from submitting.

;tldr I just want the text value from my text field so I can do some validation, but it's always empty.

**edit**

Let me know if I can "close" questions. The problem was how I bound the function to the button, which I hadn't even considered. Be careful with those "()"

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the keyword "search" to something else like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSearch() {
        var t = document.getElementById('t');
        alert(t.type);
        alert(t.value);
    }
</script>
```

Then this will work:

```
<input type="text" name="t" id="t" />
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" />
<a href="#" onclick="doSearch(); return false;">do search</a>
```